# Gradient white lines in .eps file

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, print-design, gradient

I designed a vector in Adobe Illustrator CS6, but when saved as an .eps file, white vertical lines appear in my gradient.

[image http://img823.imageshack.us/img823/772/28292306.png](http://img823.imageshack.us/img823/772/28292306.png)

What is happening? I've tried rasterizing the vector at 300 PPI with anti-aliasing, but the edges look jagged (but I really want to keep it as a vector anyway)

Does anyone have any idea what I could do?

**Additional info:**
The lines appear when I place the .eps file into Photoshop. When I open it in Illustrator though, it is as smooth as a baby's behind. I saved it in Illustrator EPS CS6.

Comment: It looks like ImageShack has removed this image and replaced it with a banner ad. Do you know if you still have a copy of the original image around?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're saving to an old EPS format and the gradient is being converted into many objects and a mask. Saving as a newer EPS format or as a PDF should fix the issue.

Q: Are the lines just in the preview, or also in the artwork when you open it up? Is the gradient still intact when you open the EPS again in Illustrator?

Comment: The lines only appear when **placing** the file in Photoshop. If I **open** it in Photoshop though, it prompts me to rasterize the file. That rasterized image is smooth - no white lines. So I guess I could conclude that there's nothing wrong with my EPS file, just that I can't place it in Photoshop...